Why is the data not being saved in current_states in Telebot? I add them using the method bot.add_data
I add them using the method bot.add_data and immediately after that, I print the result from bot.current_states.get_data(), but for some reason, the list is empty.
I tried asking the neural networks, but I didn't get a proper answer from them; maybe someone here can help
from telebot import TeleBot, types, util

bot = TeleBot(config.TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['set_my_currency'])
def set_my_currency(message: types.Message):
    args = util.extract_arguments(message.text).strip()
    
    if bot.get_state(
            user_id=message.from_user.id,
            chat_id=message.chat.id,
    ) is None:
        bot.set_state(
            user_id=message.from_user.id,
            chat_id=message.chat.id,
            state=None
        )

    bot.add_data(
        user_id=message.from_user.id,
        chat_id=message.chat.id,
        default_currency=args
    )
    print(bot.current_states.get_data(
        chat_id=message.chat.id,
        user_id=message.from_user.id
    ))

